# How to make a HorizontalFieldManager clickable in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, software-design

I'm developing an application in BlackBerry and I have many `HorizontalFieldManager`s filled with components like shown in the image below:

[image: My HorizontalFieldManager filled with components]

And I have to add many `HorizontalFieldManager`s like these within a `for` loop which are dynamically populated. When taken together, it looks like a single row in a list. So far, I have been able to do this.

But the problem is, **the user should be able to click a "row" like this**. But as the `HorizontalFieldManager` is not focusable or clickable, and because it has 4 components inside it and all 4 are equally important, I have not been able to figure-out a way to do this.

So can anyone please suggest a way to do what I'm trying? Basically, the user should be able to click a "row" which is shown in the image. This "row" is made up of many components (2 `HorizontalFieldManager`s, 1 `VerticalFieldManager`, 1 `BitmapField` and 3 `LabelFields`).

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

BBdev directly answered your question, but as you noticed, the performance is quite slow.  This is because using a manager to stamp out hundreds of rows like this adds a lot of overhead to the layout step of the UI.  Layout will run against all of those managers, every time something changes on the screen - including each time you add a new row. This is fundamentally quadratic.

The way to speed this up is to use a [ListField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html) instead. The one pain point of a ListField is that you have to do the drawing directly, instead of relying on the standard OS fields.  But the advantage is that the ListField performs very quickly - each row has a fixed height, so the ListField can quickly determine which rows are visible, and then call the paint code just for those rows.

This means the work scales with the visible size of the field, instead of the virtual size of the field.  This is a very desirable property to maintain when writing UI code, as the virtual depth of a UI has no bounds, but the physical screen has a fixed number of pixels, so by scaling the work with the visible portion of the UI, you maintain good performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Didn't think it worked that way.. But can you please tell me a way to get the UI shown in the picture using a `ListField`? I mean, the Image on the right, and the multiple `LabelField`s, and so on?

Comment: You will have to do your own row drawing using all the methods of the Graphics object.  A LabelField is just calling Graphics.drawText, so you can do that within the drawing code for the row.

Answer (score 2):

The below code will make your `HorizontalFieldManager` clickable, And add your component in this Hfm as you want.

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Touchscreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.NullField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class sample extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener{

 HorizontalFieldManager logInDetailManager=null;
 int background_color=0;

 public sample() {

logInDetailManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH|Field.FOCUSABLE){
    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            int height=40;
        super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), height);
        setExtent(Display.getWidth(), height);
    }
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

        graphics.setBackgroundColor(background_color);
        graphics.clear();
        invalidate();
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
    protected void onFocus(int direction) {
        super.onFocus(direction);
        background_color=Color.RED;
        invalidate();
    }
    protected void onUnfocus() {
        invalidate();
        background_color=Color.GREEN;

    }
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {

        if(Touchscreen.isSupported()){
            return false;
        }else{
            fieldChangeNotify(1);
            return true;
        }

    }
    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message)
    {
        if (TouchEvent.CLICK == message.getEvent())
        {
            FieldChangeListener listener = getChangeListener();
            if (null != listener)
                this.setFocus();
                listener.fieldChanged(this, 1);
        }
        return super.touchEvent(message);
    }
};
logInDetailManager.setChangeListener(this);
logInDetailManager.add(new LabelField("hello"));
logInDetailManager.add(new NullField(Field.FOCUSABLE));
add(logInDetailManager);
add(new LabelField("good",Field.FOCUSABLE));    
}

  public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {            
if(field==logInDetailManager){                  
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {                          
        public void run() {                                 
            Dialog.inform("Hi how are you?");                          
        }                    
    });          
}   
}

}
```

Hope this will help you . Cheers :)

Comment: Its working perfectly! Thanks a lot :)  Can you please tell me what's the purpose of the part- `UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {});` and within that, showing a dialog VS showing a dialog directly?

Comment: Your code works great, but my application suddenly got really slow and laggy... Any idea why this is? I think its got something to do with my application having about 150+ such `HorizontalFieldManager`s?

Comment: if you dont use `UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {});` you will get Run time exception. Because you are not on event thread.

Comment: if you have so many row in the screen then surely go for the ListField, If you had told that you have to add that much of rows i wont suggest you this. But surely you can use ListField for that as @Michael Donohue suggested.

Answer (score 0):

How to handle the focus color when you have an array of horizontal fields instead?

```
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        logInDetailManager[i] = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.FOCUSABLE) {
```

Since one item of the array is always focused the whole list is all red.